# Disable concurrent or simultaneous HTTP requests AXIOS

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, axios, refresh-token

We are having a trouble with our refresh authentication token flow, where if multiple requests are made with the same expired access token at the same time, all of them would make backend to refresh the token and would have different refreshed tokens in their responses. Now when the next request is made, the refresh token of the last response would be used which may or may not be latest.

One solution to this problem is to have UI (which is using axios in vue) send only one request at a time. So if a token is refreshed, the following request would have the latest token.

Hence **I am wondering if axios has a default option to disable simultaneous requests** as I couldn't find anything online about it. Another solution would be to maintain a queue of requests, where each request is only sent when a response (either success or fail) is received for the previous request(manual option). I understand that this might decrease the performance as it may seem in the UI, but it would also take the load off backend.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I found [here](https://gist.github.com/mkjiau/650013a99c341c9f23ca00ccb213db1c) is to use interceptor:

```
let isRefreshing = false;
let refreshSubscribers = [];

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: Config.API_URL,
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
 return response;
}, error => {
  const { config, response: { status } } = error;
  const originalRequest = config;

  if (status === 498) { //or 401
    if (!isRefreshing) {
      isRefreshing = true;
      refreshAccessToken()
        .then(newToken => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          onRrefreshed(newToken);
        });
    }

    const retryOrigReq = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      subscribeTokenRefresh(token => {
        // replace the expired token and retry
        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        resolve(axios(originalRequest));
      });
    });
    return retryOrigReq;
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
});

subscribeTokenRefresh(cb) {
  refreshSubscribers.push(cb);
}

onRrefreshed(token) {
  refreshSubscribers.map(cb => cb(token));
}
```

Comment: Wont this send simultaneous refresh requests if it catches multiple requests’ errors at the same time? Means you are refreshing token multiple times, and may get out of sync with the backend. Which was the original problem. The way Its implemented in our system is that refresh flow is a part of service calls and is not a separate call. The way I resolved it yesterday is comparing expiring_time in the refreshed token with the one with client. This way you are sure that you are using the latest token for all following requests.

Comment: No, the idea of the approach above is to call refreshAccessToken() once and then to update all the subscribers with the only requested fresh token. You could follow the link to see some comments and forks, but the general idea should work in your case.